# How to access vivContext when AccessVivContext is not the Goal?

Tags: bixby

I'm trying to make vivContext info available in my capsule.

I've looked [here:](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/user-context) And I can get the context in my capsule if I set AccessVivContext as the goal of a training utterance. But how do I access it generally?

I've tried simply entering a vivContext property in the structure my action is returning.

```
action (myAction) {
  description (do the thing)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (locale) { // this is in vivContext
      ...

    }
  }
  output(myOutput)
}
```

and I've defined a primitive type "locale" to be returned in myOutput structure:

```
structure (myOutput) {
  description (...)
   property (locale) {
     type (locale) // hoping to return $vivContext.locale here
     min (Required) max (One)
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be calling the AccessVivContext.js to get the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you define the endpoint?  $vivContext is a special variable that you can define at the javascript level.  No need to pass it in from an action.  This is how I'd suggest coding it.

1. Define an Action

> action (GetLocale) {
>            type (Constructor)
>            output(Locale)
>          }

2. Define a concept

> text(Locale)

3. Define getLocale.js

> module.exports.function = function getLocale ($vivContext) {
>           return $vivContext.locale;
>       }

4. Map your Action to the Javascript code

> action-endpoints {
>           action-endpoint (GetLocale) {
>           accepted-inputs ($vivContext)
>             local-endpoint ("getLocale.js")
>           }
>         }

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/user-context